# Deleting Non-Alpha Chars Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

i want to delete all characters except a-zA-Z0-9 and _ chracter. How can do that in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/","",$string);
```

Or

```
preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]/i","",$string);
```

Or

```
preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:][:digit:]_]/","",$string)
```

Comment: Can't `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` be shortened to `\W`?

Comment: Worth mentioning a caveat with `\W`: assumes English locale.