# preg_replace delete special chars

Tags: php, regex

wondering how I can replace all special chars on my string like: `hello this is a test!`

I've wrote this code:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", ' ', $text);
```

This works need more flexibility to allow special chars like `áéíóú...` and remove only certain chars like: `:!"#$%&/()=?¿¡`...

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting Non-Alpha Chars Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197388/deleting-non-alpha-chars-regular-expressions)

Comment: See also many many others...  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+preg_replace+alpha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$text = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u", ' ', $text);`

This will match all characters that are not letters or numbers and will treat Unicode letters appropriately.

Comment: +1; will need to be combined with `/u` modifier if the strings are UTF-8 encoded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920188/regexp-greek-chars-by-number/5920342#5920342